# How to open a Excel file from QTP Resultsviewer

Tags: excel, qtp

I want to include a Link in `Reporter.ReportEvent` Statement to open a Excel file for further details of a TEST. So for extra details user should be able to click on a link in **QTP** result viewer then a Excel file will be opened with detailed information.

How can I do this Please help.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,You cannot create link using  `Reporter.ReportEvent`. It can be used for purposes mentioned [here](http://mercuryquicktestprofessional.blogspot.in/2008/04/qtp-and-reporter-objects.html).

If I am not wrong , you want to see data table of test and so want to link it to QTP Result Viewer. QTP result viewer already has this functionality. You can see data table of all test including Non-reusable Actions as well as External Actions.

Open Result in Result Viewer Go to   View - Data table.Please note that this data table shows run time data.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the answer but I really want open a External file (XX.CSV) from the resultviewer related to one of my results. Below the "Detail"column in Result viewer I want put a link like "click here" and if the user clicks there a EXTERNAL Excel CSV file must be opened.

Comment: See: http://www.learnqtp.com/forums/newthread.php?fid=4&processed=1    for a picture